# how to write html in inline JavaScript, with CSS inline style

Tags: javascript, html

I need to write some html in inline JavaScript, with CSS inline style, how to do so

something like this `<p><span style="color: #ff0000;">test</span></p>`

```
<button class="pop-up display-screen" id="targetElement111"
    (click)="targetElement='targetElement111';model.title='';
    model.content='/*need to write some htmlhere*/';
    customTarget.open()">Open myModal
</button>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include HTML in the string, and escape the quotes

```html
 <button class="pop-up display-screen" id="targetElement111"
    (click)="targetElement='targetElement111';model.title='';model.content='<p><span style=\"color: #ff0000;\">test</span></p>';customTarget.open()">Open
    myModal</button>
```